# How to display unique records without using distinct?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL. I have Table as Test and columns are A, B, C. In column A values are like:

```
1000,
1000,
1000,
2000,
2000,
3000
```

Result would be from column A:

```
  A
1000
2000
3000
```

Note: Except using Distinct syntax,. 
Select Distinct A from Test;

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
Select A from Test GROUP BY A
```

`Group by`, groups all the similar values of a specified column into one value (group).

[Oracle Demo](https://rextester.com/YTUHFI16813)

Although, `Group By` is a standard sql and it doesn't matter what database you use.

Comment: It gives only  one record 1000, but my result like 1000, 2000, 3000

Comment: @NarasimhaL I provided demo to the answer. Check the link and see if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  someData INT
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (DEFAULT, 1000),
                     (DEFAULT, 1000),
                     (DEFAULT, 2000),
                     (DEFAULT, 1000),
                     (DEFAULT, 2000),
                     (DEFAULT, 3000),
                     (DEFAULT, 3000);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT someData
FROM A
GROUP BY someData;
```

**Output**

```
| someData |
| -------- |
| 1000     |
| 2000     |
| 3000     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vAdEDqN9xMUevF5KbveAeu/0)

Comment: Thanks Cid for provided detail info in MySQL, But my Data base is SQL,